# What could I read to understand better multivariable calculus?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, graphing-functions

I´m an economics student, and recently I started a multivariable calculus course. I´m struggling with the graphics of the functions, I would like to know if there is a book or PDF that contains at least the basic forms of two variable functions (linear, quadratic, etc). I would be very pleased if you help me. Thank you.

Comment: Surfaces from standard quadratic equations are shown [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Euclidean_space), but having those graphs in mind is not often helpful in multivariable calculus.

Comment: Not aware of such books on introductory level, sorry. The 2d surfaces in 3d space are hard to visualize well on a static page. You really want the ability to rotate them to see things better. Perhaps it would be a better to learn how to plot them using say Python/Matlab/R?

Comment: Thank you! I´ll check it out those programs and the Wikipedia page seems useful for what I´m looking for. I thought that maybe there was a book or something, that explains functions at the same way you study one variable functions in high school ( quadratic, trigonometric, exponential, etc).